# Minimize or bring back sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a Voip calling app using CallKit and when call received, it will open a view call IncomingView in a sheet in my SwiftUI app. So far so good. But i want to minimize the sheet and can navigate to other pages and preferably shows a green bar at the navigation (similar to WhatApp) that indicates the call is going on and when i tap there, it should bring back my "IncomingView".

here is my code:

```
  struct MainView: View {
     let acceptPublishser = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: Notification.Name.DidCallAccepted)
let endPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: Notification.Name.DidCallEnd)
     var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
                TabView {
                    TabListView()
                    
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
                        }
                    
                    ContactListView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Contacts", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                        }
                    
                    ProfileView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Profile", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                        }
                }
                .padding(0)
                .onAppear(){
                    self.showModal = MyCallDelegate.shared.isIncomingCall  
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showModal){
                    IncomingCallView() // -> Present IncomingCallview() as sheet
                }
                .accentColor(Color(.green))
            }.onReceive(self.acceptPublishser, perform: { output in
                showModal = true
            })
            .onReceive(self.endPublisher, perform: { output in
                showModal = false
            })
    }
    }
    
    
    struct IncomingCallView: View {
     var body: some View {
            
            
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("callerId").foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Timer").foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    }
```